# Java Play Framework Json BadRequest

Tags: java, json, post, playframework, bad-request

I am very new with Play Framework and I was doing a tutorial, but I have a little issue.

I am trying to send a JSON POST Request, and see if I can get the request properly or not.

I am using "Advanced Rest Client" in Chrome for testing and send the POST msg.

I don't know why, I am getting a Bad Request error message every time that send any msg.

My  code:

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
public static Result createRutines(){
    JsonNode json=request().body().asJson();
    if(json==null){
        return badRequest("The JSON is Empy");
    }else{
        return ok("Arrived");
    }
}
```

I will appreciate all your help.

I couldn't attach the image  of Advance Rest Client because I don't have enough reputation here.

Comment: could you please add the body of the response? How big is the JSON you are sending? Have you tried it with curl? What is in your `routes` file?

Comment: Make sure that when sending the JSON data you set the correct content type. ie application/json.

Comment: It would help if you posted your JSON body thats being sent

Comment: Thanks all for your quick replies. I am only sending one tag {"name":"Hello"}. I put the content-type:application/json but the same issue, bad request and show the msg. The JSON is Empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you are not posting invalid JSON or you are not setting the correct content-type.

To check that your JSON is valid you can use http://jsonlint.com/

In the second case, you can just add the `Content-Type: application/json` header to your request, or you can use [`TolerantJson`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/java/play/mvc/BodyParser.TolerantJson.html) instead:

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.TolerantJson.class)
public static Result createRutines(){
    // (...)
}
```

Comment: Wow, the Json is valid :) and the content-type is setted. But I change what you said, Json to TolerantJson and is working perfectly. But i want to learn why is working this way and not the other?. I am the guy that wants to learn which way is better not only to see that something works XD. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @aleyango I think the only difference between Json and TolerantJson parsers is that TolerantJson does not check for the contentType header. So you probably are not passing that header correctly.